# Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: laravel-8, webextension-polyfill

I'm trying to run a login page on my Laravel project, but I get this error on the console :

> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

If you have any ideas, please help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's affecting your app, because this error is related to the **AdBlock** extension.
You can either disable/uninstall the extension, or use incognito window.